# How to configure Nightwatch.js + Selenium Hub + Appium + real mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, selenium, appium, nightwatch.js

I have a working selenium configuration with a selenium hub which is my entry point for firefox/chrome desktop tests, launched via Nightwatch.js.

Now I would like to add tests for mobile devices, so, after some search, I've configured an Appium on a Mac, plugged with my hub as below:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "Safari",
            "platformName": "iOS",
            "platformVersion": "9.3",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "platform": "MAC"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "url":"http://192.168.24.222:4723/wd/hub",
        "host": "192.168.24.222",
        "port": 4723,
        "maxSession": 1,
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "hubHost": "selenium-hub-host"
    }
}
```

For now I would like to:

1. Configure a virtual device with Appium (I'm lost with the official documentation and I'm not familiar with Apple devices)
2. Have a proper Nightwatch test configuration to run on them
3. Add one or more real devices on the Appium side

Any help is welcome, thanks

**Edit**: I've achieved 1. and 2. by enhance capabilities in both nightwatch task def and appium capabilities:

On Nightwatch.js:

```
"ios": {
    "desiredCapabilities" : {
        "browserName" : "Safari",
        "deviceName": "iPhone Simulator",
        "platformName" : "iOS",
        "platform" : "MAC",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
    }
}
```

On Appium nodeconf.json:

```
"capabilities": [
    {
        "browserName": "Safari",
        "platformName": "iOS",
        "platformVersion": "9.3",
        "deviceName": "iPhone Simulator",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "platform": "MAC"
    }
]
```

but now I'm stuck with real devices, it's doesn't want to register my nodeconf on the selenium hub (invalid param, apparently):

```
{
    "browserName": "Safari",
    "platformName": "iOS",
    "platformVersion": "8.1",
    "deviceName": "testmac’s iPad",
    "udid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "maxInstances": 1,
    "platform": "MAC"
}
```

Here is my hub grid:
[image: selenium hub grid]

Answer (score 0):

To connect more than one iOS device you have to use workaround described [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5925). You have to provide additional parameters while starting Appium:

```
.node -p 6001 -U --tmp /temp/dir1 &
.node -p 6002 -U --tmp /temp/dir2 &
```

Running Android devices is not limited this way. I dont know if this is the right attitude, but it worked for me few weeks ago. Config file - huaweiG6.json:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "HuaweiG6",
      "deviceName":"8c34fd0c5a94",
      "version":"4.3",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "platform":"ANDROID",
      "newCommandTimeout":"30",
      "deviceReadyTimeout":5
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":10800,
    "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4727,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "172.17.0.232"
  }
}
```

And starting Appium with command:

```
appium --nodeconfig huaweiG6.json -p 4727 -cp 4727 -U 8c34fd0c5a94
```

-U parameter is equivalent to -udid as described [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-on-real-ios-devices). You can get the id by running:

```
adb devices
```

Which is possible after installing Android SDK. Your deviceName parameter should have the same value. If you are having problems with connecting to the hub, try to change hubHost parameter - it should be domain or IP of a running hub instance.

I have made my test to run parallel by using runners from https://github.com/michaeltamm/junit-toolbox. Alternative for Java users is to use Maven surefire plugin http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Good luck